# How to create a pandas dataframe inside a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a function to split the sentences into words and i need to create features out of them. I am encountering following issues
1. when i use a list to hold all values, when i retrieve them,all the features are created as a single column, whereas i need each of them as single column
2. getting zero division error even though I am using if condition to check if the count is zero

```
def token_features(q1,q2):
    stats = [0.0]*10

    q1_tokens = q1.split()
    q2_tokens = q2.split()

    q1_words = set([word for word in q1_tokens if word not in STOP_WORDS])
    q2_words = set([word for word in q2_tokens if word not in STOP_WORDS])
    common_word_count = len(set(q1_words) & set(q2_words))

    s1_stops = set([word for word in q1_tokens if word in STOP_WORDS])
    s2_stops = set([word for word in q2_tokens if word in STOP_WORDS])
    stop_word_count = len(s1_stops & s2_stops)    

    common_token_count = len(set(q1_tokens) & set(q2_tokens))

    if (common_word_count==0 or stop_word_count==0 or common_token_count==0):
        pass

    stats[0] = common_word_count/min(len(q1_words),len(q2_words))
    stats[1] = common_word_count/max(len(q1_words),len(q2_words))    
    stats[2] = stop_word_count/min(len(s1_stops),len(s2_stops))
    stats[3] = stop_word_count/max(len(s1_stops),len(s2_stops))
    stats[4] = common_token_count/min(len(q1_tokens),len(q2_tokens))
    stats[5] = common_token_count/max(len(q1_tokens),len(q2_tokens)) 
    stats[6] = int(q1_tokens[-1] == q2_tokens[-1])
    stats[7] = int(q1_tokens[0] == q2_tokens[0])
    stats[8] = abs(len(q1_tokens) - len(q2_tokens))
    stats[9] = (len(q1_tokens) + len(q2_tokens))/2 

    return stats
```

what i need is
1. how to create a dataframe inside the function and add it to another dataframe. i.e, I have a Dataframe named out, which has columns a,b. now i need to create a dataframe inside the function and add those columns of the dataframe to "out" dataframe.

Comment: so you mean that you want `stats` to be a row rather than a column?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you are trying to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1': ['Yes','3'], 'col_2': ["2.0","Yes"]}
base_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
def appendToDf(base_df):
    data = {'new1': ['Yes','3'], 'new2': ["2.0","Yes"]}
    dfNew=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    out_df=pd.concat([base_df,dfNew], axis=1)
    return out_df

appendToDf(base_df)
```

Comment: Not exactly juske. I have a dataframe with "question1" and "question2". I need to parse them to creature features and add those features to the main dataframe.

Comment: Are these dataframes the same lenght?

Comment: Yes. They are of same length.